# php code not fetching file as expected

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have looked at this piece of code for a long time and don't seen to know where the problem is..

```
function getComment($topic_id){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE topic_id='$topic_id' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 20";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    //the "id of the comment willl be used in maing the like box"
    while($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $qry = "SELECT username, avatar2 FROM user WHERE user_id='".$output['user_id']."'";
    $rst = mysql_query($qry);
    $out = mysql_fetch_assoc($rst);
    $disp = '
        <div class="tmain">
            <h3 class="underlinebold">Topic Title<span class="not_left">
                <ul>
                    <li><i class="icon-time" style="margin-top:5px;"></i>time: '. getTime($output["time"]) .' ago</li>
                    <li><i class="icon-pencil" style="margin-top:5px;"></i>Edit</li>
                    <li><span class="badge badge-inverse">#2</span></li>
                </ul>
            </span></h3>
            <div class="postWrap">
                <div class="userInfo">
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="'. $out["avatar2"] .'" /></li>
                        <li>'. $out["username"] .'</li>
                        <li>'. commentNo($output["user_id"]) .'</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="comment">
                    <div class="commentText">'.
                     $output["content"].'</div>
                    <ul class="below">
                        <li><i class="icon-flag" style="margin-top:3px;"> </i>Report</li>
                        <li><i class="icon-edit" style="margin-top:3px;"> </i>Quote</li>
                        <li><i class="icon-thumbs-down" style="margin-top:3px;"> </i>Mtcheew...(<span>0</span>)</li>
                        <li><i class="icon-thumbs-up" style="margin-top:3px;"> </i>Correct!(<span>0</span>)</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ';
    return $disp;
    }

}
```

The code is suppose to get all the comments related to a particular topic and show them on the topic page.. but it shows only the last posted code and nothing else.. i don't know where i am getting all wrong..

you could see the effect here [test forum](http://test.nairation.com) So please if you guys could help...

Comment: Shouldn't you be looping through the result set?

Comment: You're returning the value of $disp after the first iteration. Also, you need to use PDO instead of mysql_, learn about SQL joins and MVC (and code formatting...).

Comment: i am a newbie at this... i know there is a mistake somewhere but i can't just figure it out because i am accessing 2 tables and don't know which on to use for the loop without tampering the other query

Comment: @andrewsi He is, it's just hard to see because it's not indented properly.

Comment: Why are you using two queries instead of a single query with a JOIN?

Comment: @Barmar don't know how to execute sql statements with a join.

Comment: @Barmar, his code is basically while(fetch()) { return $disp; }, there's no looping happening.

Comment: @DCoder Ugh, his broken indentation got me, too.

Comment: @DCoder please could you help..wanna learn that's why i came here please..

Answer (score 4):

Each time through the loop it replaces the value of `$disp` with the current row. You need to append them instead of replacing, i.e.

```
$disp .= '<div class="tmain"> ... </div>';
      ^
```

Also, the `return $disp;` statement needs to be **outside** the `while` loop. You're returning during the first iteration of the loop.

And rather than doing a separate query for each username/avatar, you should do it in the main query with a join:

```
SELECT c.*, u.username, u.avatar
FROM comment c
JOIN user u ON u.user_id = c.user_id
WHERE topic_id = '$topic_id'
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: i should keep concatenating the $display...

Comment: can i use ur code exactly as it is

Comment: You'll need to change other things to match. For instance, `$out['avatar']` becomes `$output['avatar']` because you're no longer doing the second `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: It's not rocket science.

Comment: yeah i know it ain't my fault not yet experienced still learning..but i am very grateful...

Comment: Sorry, just getting frustrated at all the people who think they can create web sites without actually knowing how to program. Not knowing about joins means you don't really know SQL.

Comment: you want to take it out on me or wat...other people come on here to ask questions too..so don't take yourself so high..and yeah i can build website... nd besides you weren't the one that answered the question and yet you are making the loudest noise..you've just lost my respect...